# Jersey2 Rest API return enum values

Tags: java, rest, enums, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have the following enum class:

```
public enum ResearchData {
 HEIGHT("Height"), WIDTH("Width"), WEIGHT("Height"), LENGTH("Length"), ITEM_DESCRIPTION(
            "Item Description"), IMAGE_URL("Image URL");

    private String value;

    private ResearchData(String mimeType) {
        value = mimeType;
    }

    public String getDisplayValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static ResearchData fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v);
    }
}
```

How shall I expose it via Jersey2 Rest API? (as a json object) Using `Options/Get`? what is the recommended way?

Comment: Why do you want to expose an Enum as a REST resource? What do you want to do with this resource?

Comment: Client side needs to display the value e.g. Image URL but send the key in a @POST call - IMAGE_URL. this will tell him which values to display

Comment: A common way is to pass the object in your post and marshall/unmarshall it in both sides (client and server) using something like `jackson` or `moxy`. Personally I use `moxy` but honestly I don't recall anymore why I decided it, and I hear that `jackson` might be a bit more straightforward. (However, `moxy` is fine, don't expect a big difference)

Comment: Correct - but should it be OPTIONS or GET? and what should be the method signature?